# Non-differentiation

Tags: survey, methodology, psychology, internet

I'm trying to assess the level of non-differentiation for a web survey I am doing. It features six pages of several Likert items on each page with a 6 point scale, followed by a seventh page of several items with a 10 point scale.

I'm looking for the best formula to evaluate non-differentiation, and particularly one that is not sensitive to the number of response items.

I found this paper presented to AAPOR that could be used as a model, but I'm not sure if it is sensitive to the number of response categories, i.e. could I compare the seventh page with the first six?

http://papor.org/files/2006/Taylor2006.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with the term of art *non-differentiation*, but two ideas come up.

1. Equivalence testing provides a framework for testing whether quantities are not more different than some *a priori* specified level. So one approach would be to test for equivalence of items on your seventh page (or whatever), with the usual caveats about [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). You can read about one kind of equivalence testing [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/tost/info).
2. If non-differentiation means that responses to items on the seventh page (or whatever) tend toward a specific value (e.g. the middle of the scale), then you could also test whether each item is different than that middle. Again, multiple comparisons yadda yadda...